# Clarification on the "Comparison Principle" Found in Chapter 3 of Nonlinear Systems by Hassan K. Khalil (Details in Body)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, lipschitz-functions

In the book the following Lemma is given (Lemma 3.4, Comparison Lemma):

> Consider the the scalar differential equation
>   $$\dot u =f(t,u), \qquad u(t_0)=u_0$$
>   where $f(t,u)$ is continuous in $t$ and locally Lipschitz in $u$, for all $t \geq 0$ and all $u \in J \subset R$. Let $[t_0,T)$ ($T$ could be infinity) be the maximal interval of existence of the solution $u(t)$, and suppose $u(t) \in J$ for all $t \in [t_0,T)$. Let $v(t)$ be a continuous function whose upper right hand derivative $D^+v(t)$ satisfies the differential inequality
>   $$D^+v(t) \leq f(t,v(t)),\qquad v(t_0) \leq u_0$$
>   with $v(t) \in J$ for all $t \in [t_0,T)$. Then, $v(t) \leq u(t)$ for all $t \in [t_0,T)$.

Following this is an example (example 3.8):

> The scalar differential equation
>   $$\dot x =f(x) = -(1+x^2)x, \qquad x(0)=a$$
>   has a unique solution on $[0,t_1)$, for some $t_1>0$, because $f(x)$ is locally Lipschitz. Let $v(t)=x^2(t)$. The function $v(t)$ is differentiable and its derivative is given by
>   $$\dot v(t)=2x(t) \dot x(t)=-2x^2(t)-2x^4(t) \leq -2x^2(t)$$
>   ...

This example then continues, but my confusion is on the last line where the book says $f(t,v(t)) = -2x^2(t)$ for the inequality. This doesn't make sense to me. I have been trying to figure this out for several hours now and haven't made any progress. I thought you'd simply substitute $x^2(t)$ into $f(x)=-(1+x^2)x$ given that $D^+v(t) \leq f(t,v(t))$ from the lemma.

Obviously I'm missing something in my understanding...

Edit: here is a link to a [.pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Muhammad_Ahsan23/post/What_is_the_general_principle_of_designing_the_switching_control_in_sliding_mode_control/attachment/59d62f0dc49f478072e9f5e3/AS%3A272534484783104%401441988692243/download/H-K-Khalil-Nonlinear-Systems-3rd-Edition-2002.pdf) see page 102-103

Comment: Note that this example is also Bernoulli, so that you can also compute the exact solution, using $u=x^{-2}$.

Comment: @LutzL I'm sorry, but I am not sure how that helps me. unless this is just a side comment and not an answer. I am new here. (:

Comment: Hmm, but what exactly is not clear? We have $v(x)=x^2$, and $\dot{v}(t) = 2v(x)\dot{x}(t) = -2x^2(t)-2x^4(t)$. Obviously, $-2x^4$ is not positive, and $\dot{v}(t) \le -2x^2(t) = -2v(x(t))$ for all $t$. So ve have $\dot{v} \le -2v$. Then we replace the inequality with equality for some other function, e.g., $\dot{u}=-2u$, $u(0)=v(0)=x^2(0)$. Then the solution $v(t)$ can be compared in the defined sence with the solution $u(t)$, where the solution $u(t)$ can be easily computed sine it is a linear ODE.

Comment: @Arastas my confusion is in $\dot v(t) \leq -2x^2(t)$. Where does the $-2x^2(t)$ come from?

Comment: From $v(t)=x(t)^2$ you get $\dot v=2x\dot x=-2x^2(1+x^2)=-2v(1+v)\le-2v$ and thus $v(t)\le v(0)e^{-2t}$, see also Grönwall lemma.

Comment: Since $v(t)=2x^2(t)$, you have $\frac{d}{dt}v(t) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}f(x)$, where $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=2x$.

Comment: @LutzL I understand the derivative but my problem is with the RHS of the inequality, $-2x^2$. How is this part found? From the lemma, the RHS is, $f(t,v(t))$, or in this case just, $f(v(t))$. I don't see how that is $-2x^2$. I am new to this as I just got this book and I took DiffEq 3yrs ago. Sorry about my ignorance, I feel like I am asking a trivial question. I will also take a look at Gronwell soon as well, it seems the international edition of this book doesn't have the appendix where you would find this...

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ in the comparison lemma is not the same $f$ as in the example with the ODE $\dot x =-(1+x^2)x$. I think that from here stems the confusion. From the choice of the Lyapunov function $V=x^2$ it should be clear that $\dot V=2x\dot x\leq-2x^2$. That is,  $\dot V\leq -2V$. So regarding the lemma, setting $V=:u$, we have $\dot u= \Xi(u)$ with $\Xi=-2x^2=-2V$. Or the same with $\Xi =:f$ when using the same notation of the lemma.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the theorem to the example, then the "named" ODE function for the cited lemma is $u'=f(t,u)=-2u$.

This is then compared to the example ODE that is to be analyzed by providing a bound. With the change of variables $v=x^2$ one gets a compatible form
$$
v'=2xx'=-2x^2(1+x^2)=-2v-2v^2=g(t,v).
$$
Now we get indeed for solutions of this ODE
$$v'=g(t,v)\le f(t,v),$$ as $-2v^2\le 0$.

In consequence, the unknown solution $v$ is bounded by the known solution with the same initial value $$v(t)\le u(t)=v(0)e^{-2t},\\~\\ |x(t)|\le|x(0)|e^{-t}.$$

---

*Remark:* the equation for $v$ is also directly solvable as Bernoulli equation, $$(v^{-1})'=-v^{-2}v'=2(v^{-1})+2,$$ so that $$v(t)^{-1}+1=(v(0)^{-1}+1)e^{2t},$$ and solving that for $v$
$$
v(t)=\frac{v(0)e^{-2t}}{1+v(0)(1-e^{-2t})}=v(0)e^{-2t}-\frac{v(0)^2e^{-2t}(1-e^{-2t})}{1+v(0)(1-e^{-2t})}.
$$
which is indeed, for $t> 0$, smaller than $u(t)$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps but I think it is obvious for me that I need to take a step back and study some previous topics in the book and learn more about gronwall.